# Set node size by attribute in Gephi

Tags: igraph, gephi, graphml

I'm generating graphs for Gephi in igraph and I used to be able to set the node size as an attribute in igraph and then it would appear as an attribute in Gephi and I could use that attribute to set the size of the node in Gephi.

The graphml I'm generating has size included:
8
and when I'm loading the file into Gephi it says "Node property found: size" but then the size that is shown when the node is selected is not the same as the size in the graphml (in this case it's 28.8889 when selected in the Data Laboratory).

I can't see size as an attribute anywhere, or work out how to use the v_size in the graphml as the node size.

Is this something different with Gephi or am I setting up my graphml wrongly?